# Deleting a row from MySQL by ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql-delete

I'm using to create a table using MySQL table contents. The problem is I'm trying to create a delete (x) button for each row in the table (Delete column).

```
 <?php
$html = "<table>";
$html .= "<tr>";
$html .= "<th>id</th>";
$html .= "<th>Event type</th>";
$html .= "<th>Date</th>";
$html .= "<th>Price(€)</th>";
$html .= "<th>Description</th>";
$html .= "<th>Delete</th>";
$html .= "</tr>";

foreach($event as $e){
    $html .= "<tr>";
    $html .= "<td>$e->eventId</td>";
    $html .= "<td>$e->eventType</td>";
    $html .= "<td>$e->eventDate</td>";
    $html .= "<td>$e->eventPrice</td>";
    $html .= "<td>$e->eventDescr</td>";
    $html .= "<td><--the delete button has to be here--></td>";
    $html .= "</tr>";
}

$html .= "</table>";
echo $html;
```

I've tried using a button onclick but absolutely failed. Could anyone give me any tips?

Comment: what is failing you? I also don't see any db code.

Comment: Basically i want to use the DELETE FROM table_name id some_column = eventId

Comment: you need to use `DELETE FROM table WHERE col = ?`

Comment: i'm not sure how to insert the button and what should be the function

Comment: You have two problems: 1, you haven't read the "how to ask a question" code.  Your question must show the *minimum* code required to reproduce the problem.  And 2, you haven't defined the "problem".  As the saying goes, "a problem well defined is half solved already"

Comment: $html .= "<td><input type=\"button\" value=\"X\"  onclick=\"DELETE FROM events_archive WHERE id = eventsId?\"></input></td>";

Comment: thats what i've tried.

Comment: *`<--the delete button has to be here-->`* - You can use an `href` with a `?` parameter, then use the GET array in the php/mysql section of your file or an input with a name attribute with a `<form></form>`. Your MySQL doesn't go in the onclick, it goes in the mysql/php file. There are ample scripts on the web you can search for, "how to delete a row in mysql php".

Comment: @user3099298 I don't know why you deleted your answer. You just needed to modify your answer as per the comment I left under it.

Comment: the problem is that i have completely no idea how to create a href there which will delete the row from the table :(

Answer (score 0):

My solution is only one of many possible

1) create js function to remove row and call an ajax request to delete an item from DB

```
function removeRow(item,eventId)
{
  var row = $(item).parent().parent();
  $.ajax(url: '(url_to)/remove.php?id='+eventId,
         success: function(resp)
         {
           if(resp=='OK')
           {
             row.remove();
           }
         }
  );
```

}

2) create button

```
$html .= '<td><a href="javascript:removeRow(this,'.$e->eventId.');return false;">Delete</a></td>';
```

3) create PHP script

```
<?php
//connection to DB
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbname = "dbb";
$dbuser = " ";
$dbpswd = " ";

try
{
  $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".$dbhost.";dbname=".$dbname,$dbuser,$dbpswd);
  $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  //removing event
  $count = $db->exec("DELETE FROM `someTable` WHERE id = {intval($id)}");
  //return OK if event was correctly deleted
  if($count==1)
  {
    echo 'OK';
  }
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
  //only for development version
  echo $e->getMessage();
}
die();
```

Comment: so what goes into the php script? i suppose something like DELETE FROM TABLE events_archive WHERE id = eventId?

Comment: I've described in my previous answer

Comment: my mistake now fixed

Comment: `Notice: Undefined variable: id in <url> on line 77 SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064`

Comment: thats the `$count = $db->exec("DELETE FROM `someTable` WHERE id = {intval($id)}");` line

Comment: my code is only some kind of template for your solution. I do not know structure of your DB, files etc. $id should be GET['id'] variable send via ajax request